# Simple javascript counting table rows

Tags: javascript

I'm new in web development,and I want to count all rows in a table. I have some very simple code

```
<form>
  <input type="button" value="Count Table Rows" onclick="alert(document.getElementById('tableId').rows.length);">
</form>
```

This will display an integer if I click some button. But I want it to just display in a `div` when a user access that page, or during page loads, it will automatically display the numbers.

Comment: You want to use the `onload` function instead of `onclick`.

Comment: Can you post the code for table rows?

Comment: `window.onload = function() { alert(document.getElementById('tableId').rows.length) }`?

Comment: `window.onload = function() { document.getElementById("divID").innerHTML = document.getElementById("tableId").rows.length };`

Comment: Add a on [onload event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onload) for the page, get the number of rows using your code and [get the div](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) and [display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML).

Comment: Write an external js file. In this js file get element by ID of your choice (div) and display the count using innerHTML.

Comment: There's already tons of duplicate questions on here asking how to edit the content of a div. Also, it's generally considered bad practice to use inline JavaScript.

Comment: @Jason your example code worked.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an event listener to the window object or simply add code in script tags at the end of the page.

```
<script>
// self executing function
(function() {
    var div = document.getElementById('dividhere');
    div.innerHTML = "Table Row Count : " + document.getElementById('tableId').rows.length;
})();
</script>
```

Comment: Other than using a self executing function I recommend just using JavaScript's `onload` function. `(function() {` -> `window.onload = function() {`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
  <script>
    document.write(document.getElementById('tableid').rows.length)
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't use `document.write`.

Comment: window.onload = function() { document.getElementById("divID").innerHTML = document.getElementById("tableId").rows.length }
Works for me as suggested by @Jason.But I forgot to mention in my question that I have 5 tables in my html and each one of them has different numbers of rows.Is it a good idea to have javascript in each table to count each table's rows and use the script above for each of them?